# What is the equivalent of setInterval that can be used in a gmail addon (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

In the Gmail addon, I am building I need to hit an external API every few minutes to check for a flag and then reload the addon.

The closest I can see is this : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn

However, Even when I add this scope required for this :

This has the following problems:

1. When I use the code below, I see: "Exception: The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour". <- this is a major blocker as I need to trigger every 2 mins or so.

I tried this code:

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("getContextualAddon")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
```

2. Even if this works the permission: "Allow this application to run when you are not present"
   is rather scary for the users of my addon who think the addon will do something in the background.

[image: the below authorization screen]

Is there any other way I can achieve this. I tried normal setInterval but it of course fails as this is not plain javascript (and it runs on the server).

Comment: Nope. And I'm not sure that will even run - Gmail Add-ons are not allowed to use the simple or installable triggers (e.g. to configure a spreadsheet on edit, etc.), and while not mentioned, this may apply to time-based triggers as well. Review the restrictions page.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the confirmation. Yes, I did give me an error. Exception: The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour